How to assign cost and resource usage to a project different from the project where the repository is defined in GCP Dataform
We have a dataform repository that we hope to execute for different customers with billing and resource usage (bigquery slots) taken from a customer specific GCP ProjectID.
Essentially, when instantiating a BigQuery client one can specify the default projectID and this then becomes the project that resources are spent (cost and slots).
From looking at the documentation here it looks like this should be achieved by specifying the defaultDatabase in the codeCompilationConfig when compiling.
When doing this however, we are seeing no change on either bigquery logs or resource usage, ie. they are still attributed to the projectID where the dataform repository is defined and the run logs are still all in that same project.
Is this expected behaviour, or is something amiss?
We also attempting to override the service account when invoking the compiled project, but that just executes the steps using the service account and does not affect resource usages at all it seems.

https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.repositories.compilationResults#CompilationResult
https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.repositories.workflowInvocations/create


The only workaround we've been able to find is to replicate all the dataform repositories in each customer project and execute them from that location. This will result in resource usage appearing only in the customer project.

I believe that there has been some discussion within Google about adding a feature that might provide a flag called billingProjectId .... this could be set at compile time that would identify which projectId would be billed/charged for the execution.   I haven't heard that this is committed or has a time frame.

@Kolban yes, that is precisely the configuration I am missing. Until then, we've simply mirrored the entire dataform pipeline (ie. repos) for each customer/project. Seems a pretty straight forward thing to add to the invoke method IMO.
